# Package shared code in VSTS extension

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I'm writing a VSTS extension with build/release tasks in it. Where can I put code that is used by more than one task within an extension? Can I put it anywhere in the extension file tree (eg. the `Common` folder below) and then just use that path - will those files be downloaded by every agent running any task from the extension?

The directory structure I currently have looks like this:

```
My Extension
|- MyBuildTask
|   |- MyBuildTask.ps1
|   |- task.json
|- MyReleaseTask
|   |- MyReleaseTask.ps1
|   |- task.json
|- Common
|   |- MyModule.psm1
|-vss-extension.json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you queue builds, anent only downloads the single task files, it's not able to share file between tasks. You have to pack all files the task needs in the task directory.

Comment: Thanks - the workaround I've gone for now is to copy that `Common` directory into each task at build time when I package my extension.

Comment: I did try adding this to my extension manifest: `,
                  {
                      "path":  "Common",
                      "addressable":  true,
                      "packagePath":  "/Common"
                  }` and the `Common` directory got added into the root of my extension but I couldn't find a way to get the task to reference it. Is that possible?

Comment: You should use `gulp build` to link the file. You can check [this example](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-rm-extensions), after you run `gulp build`, you'll see the `DeploymentSDK` in the common folder is linked into all tasks in extension `IISWebAppDeploy`.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it the agent installs the whole extension which means that all code in the extension should get download and be useable from any task.

Comment: No, it only downloads the files from within the individual task directory. The other tasks within the extension aren't downloaded unless they are used in teh build.